# equation working well in editor but does not compile in beamer

Tags: beamer, equations, markdown

I am using Overleaf to make a beamer style presentation. The following code works fine in the text editor but will not compile. The following code works fine in other files as well. Actually, all my equations that work fine elsewhere (I am using Typora) are not compiling here.

[UPDATE]

1. I have opened an new template. It works well without adding new
   frames.
2. Then I added only one line of code, my equation. It shows
   errors
3. Then I removed my equations. It works fine.

**The only code I added is at line 40, which is an equation.**

I have included the template links: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/examples/writing-beamer-slides-with-markdown/dnrwnjrpjjhw#.WxKytEgvyUl

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{eulervm}
\usepackage{natbib}

%% Load the markdown package
\usepackage[citations,footnotes,definitionLists,hashEnumerators,smartEllipses,tightLists=false,hybrid]{markdown}
\markdownSetup{rendererPrototypes={
 link = {\href{#2}{#1}},
 headingThree = {\begin{frame}\frametitle{#1}},
 headingFour = {\begin{block}{#1}},
 horizontalRule = {\end{block}}
}}


\usetheme{Dresden}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usecolortheme{rose}


\title{Writing Beamer Slides with Markdown}
\author{LianTze Lim}
\institute{Overleaf}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\frame{\tableofcontents}

\begin{markdown}

## How?

### We can do that?

$ Q_{ijt}^{A} \sim N (Q_{j}, \sigma^2_{A}) $

- Yeah to some extent, with \texttt{markdown} package :-)
    - __$\hash$__ and __$\hash\hash$__ for section and subsection headers (in ToC)
    - Redefine __$\hash\hash\hash$__ to start a frame and frametitle
    - (Nested) bullet and numbered lists
    - Text formatting (*italic*, **bold becomes italic + alerted**) 
    - Redefine __$\hash\hash\hash\hash$__ to start a block with title \linebreak
      and __\texttt{-{}-{}-{}-}__ to end the block
    - ___Compile with \texttt{-{}-shell-escape}___ (Overleaf does this already)
- (Alternative approaches: Pandoc, wikitobeamer)

\end{frame}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

### Caveats

- Nothing too complicated! 
- No verbatim or fragile stuff!
- No $\hash$ and \textunderscore{} characters!\linebreak 
  (I used `$\hash$` and `\textunderscore`)
- Can't pass options to frames
- __Need to write \texttt{\textbackslash end\string{frame\string}} manually!__

\end{frame}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


%%% # and ## are still sections and subsections
# Example

## Proposed Menus

%%% ### starts a frame + frametitle
### Breakfast Menu

%%% bulleted lists as usual 

- Eggs
    * scrambled
    * sunny-side-up
- Coffee
    * Americano
    * Long black
- Tea
    * Darjeeling
    * English Breakfast

%%% Due to the complicatedness of beamer frames, \end{frame} MUST appear in the source code itself and cannot be "hidden" in another command

\end{frame}

%%%%%%%%%%%

### Lunch Menu

- Spaghetti
    * Bolognese
    * Aglio olio
- Sandwiches
    * Egg
    * Ham
    * Tuna

\end{frame}

%%%%%%%%%%%

## Budgeting

### Projected Profit

1. And the answer is...
2. $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}(x-a)^n$
    #. How do we _know_ that?
    #. __Maths!__

\end{frame}

### Testing blocks

#### This is a block!

- Here is some content.
- Here's more contents.

---

\end{frame}


### Citations

- This is a book [@BookKey]
- This is an article [@ArticleKey]

\end{frame}

\end{markdown}

\begin{frame}
\renewcommand{\bibfont}{\footnotesize}
\frametitle{Bibliography}

\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{refs}

\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Comment: please, provide code in form of complete small document beginning with \documentclass{beamer}` and ending with `\end{document}`, which show your problem, not its image. your code fragment is not cause of your problem.

Comment: I am new to  markdown and not very familiar with latex. I have put documentclass there, if that is what you mean

Comment: The error message complains about line 185. You circled a different line that should be ignored by beamer.

Comment: The error message says something about `\itshape` not being valid in math mode, yet your code features no `\itshape` instructions. As your query stands, it cannot be answered. (Aside: `\itshape` is a text mode command and should therefore definitely not be used in math mode...)

Comment: @Johannes_B, the problem is caused by the equation. If I remove the equation, it will compile with no error. I have check my line 185, and there seems no error.

Comment: @Mico, I am a bit confused by textmode or math mode. In markdown, you just type the equation, it will just show up. So you mean, I should use a math mode code to type my equations?

Comment: There seems to be some terminological confusion. For sure, LaTeX does *not* employ "markdown"; instead, it's a mark-up language. (AFAICT, the term "markdown" was coined as perhaps-a-bit-too-clever pun on the term "mark-up", which is much older.) In the code you posted, the symbol `$` serves to initiate and terminate inline-style math mode. There's also a second form of math mode: display-stye math mode. How to enter equations depends crucially on whether one wishes to employ inline or display style. Please study any introduction to LaTeX to familiarize yourself with the terminology.

Comment: your claim, that this equation is cause of error, doesn't hold. it also can be compiled in overleaf with any errors or warnings (tested). you apparently overlooked real cause of your trouble.  try to exclude from document all frames before this one and see, if then you receive error. after then add frame before it and check again. repeat so many time, that you will reach a frame where is cause of your error.

Comment: Your error message mentions line 185. So the problematic code is in the frame ending at this line. That is above the position you are showing currently.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer;@Zarko. I have updated my question. I can't find the problem in the specified row.

Comment: Are you closing `}` twice on line 16? Is it right? Please, check.

Comment: please, upgrade also your code in question that it will be equal to this in image. from images i can't see, what you doing.

Comment: Don't show screenshots. Copy the code in the question. I certainly don't want to have to retype everything for a test.

Comment: @Sigur. The bracket seems fine. I removed the }, it still shows error.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer. Added it

Comment: You should open `markdown` and close it within the same `frame`

Comment: Also, `maketitle` should be inside a `frame`.

Comment: @Sigur Beamer is actually clever enough to check if `\maketitle` is called inside a frame or not and inserts a frame if necessary.

Comment: @samcarter, good to know. I don't use it too much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you have multiple `_` in your formula which markdown recognises as italic. If you want to use them as subscripts, either use the markdown package with `underscores=false` option or escape them.

**Answer 1: Escaping**

```
% !TeX program = txs:///arara
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: on, interaction: nonstopmode, shell: yes}
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathabx}

%% Load the markdown package
\usepackage[citations,footnotes,definitionLists,hashEnumerators,smartEllipses,tightLists=false,hybrid]{markdown}
\markdownSetup{rendererPrototypes={
 link = {\href{#2}{#1}},
 headingThree = {\begin{frame}\frametitle{#1}},
 headingFour = {\begin{block}{#1}},
 horizontalRule = {\end{block}}
}}

\begin{document}

\begin{markdown}

### We can do that?

$ {Q\_{ijt}} Q\_{j} $

\end{frame}

\end{markdown}

\end{document}
```

**Answer 2: `underscore=false`**

Please not that with this solution `_` can no longer be used as markdown elements.

```
% !TeX program = txs:///arara
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: on, interaction: nonstopmode, shell: yes}
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathabx}

%% Load the markdown package
\usepackage[citations,footnotes,definitionLists,hashEnumerators,smartEllipses,tightLists=false,hybrid,underscores=false]{markdown}
\markdownSetup{rendererPrototypes={
 link = {\href{#2}{#1}},
 headingThree = {\begin{frame}\frametitle{#1}},
 headingFour = {\begin{block}{#1}},
 horizontalRule = {\end{block}}
}}

\begin{document}

\begin{markdown}

### We can do that?

$ {Q_{ijt}} Q_{j} $

- Yeah to some extent, with \texttt{markdown} package :-)
    - $\hash$ and $\hash\hash$ for section and subsection headers (in ToC)
    - Redefine $\hash\hash\hash$ to start a frame and frametitle
    - (Nested) bullet and numbered lists
    - Text formatting (*italic*, **bold becomes italic + alerted**) 
    - Redefine $\hash\hash\hash\hash$ to start a block with title \linebreak
      and \texttt{-{}-{}-{}-} to end the block
    - Compile with \texttt{-{}-shell-escape} (Overleaf does this already)
- (Alternative approaches: Pandoc, wikitobeamer)

\end{frame}

\end{markdown}

\end{document}
```

Comment: How to set underscores=false?

Comment: @alphabetagamma `\usepackage[underscores=false, ....`

Comment: @samcarter, please be so kind and edit your answer where consider `underscores=false` and show, how to be changed text (list?) which in question follows equation. if i added it to your answer, it gives error (missing `$`).

Comment: @Zarko With  `underscores=false` the underscore can no longer be used for italic.  I will edit

Comment: @Zarko edited__

Comment: @samcarter, thank you. now i wonder, what result should give the line `Text formatting (*italic*, **bold becomes italic + alerted**)`. i receive italic shape for `*italic*` and boldface for `**bold become italic ... **`. from text i expect that `**bold become italic ... **` should give italic boldface text or i misunderstand this sentence?

Comment: @Zarko Disclaimer: I don't know much about markdown. As far as I understood `**...**` should be used to alert text and the exact font/color can be adjusted in some settings (no idea where they are), so it acts basically just the same as `\alert{...}` in beamer. In most cases the predefined setting for `**...**` seems to be bold text, just like it is on this site.

Comment: @Zarko If you want to know why the sentence suggested something else, you'll have to ask LianTze Lim

Comment: @samcarter, thank you for explanation. i was just curious. i don't use `markdown, actually now i don't see any benefits of `markdown` over classical `latex` :-)